# show imageview using path stored in Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-imageview, android-sqlite

I want to show image on imageView, I have the path stored in database, and want to show the image on imageView using that path.

```
String path = Utility.GetColumnValue(testdata, "path");
```

This returns me the value of in form of a path >> /drawable/image

and then

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
img.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path));
```

but my app get crashed somethings wrong

Comment: first check file existence then do file.getPath()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the bitmap from the path like that

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img_path );
    img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

or can try this one

```
String path= "@drawable/myresource.png";
int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier(path, null, getPackageName());
Drawable res = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
img.setImageDrawable(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.example.database_db_hari;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView iv;

    Button b1, b2;

    byte[] img1, image;

    Bitmap b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_activity_main_open);

        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_activity_main_show);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                DataBaseHub dbh = new DataBaseHub(MainActivity.this);

                SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

                // convert from bitmap to byte array

                b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),

                R.drawable.aass);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

                byte[] img1 = stream.toByteArray();

                cv.put(DataBaseHub.PHOTO, img1);

                db.insert(DataBaseHub.TABLENAME, null, cv);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Insert Success",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });

        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                DataBaseHub dbh = new DataBaseHub(MainActivity.this);

                SQLiteDatabase db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();

                // convert from byte array to bitmap

                Cursor c = db.query(DataBaseHub.TABLENAME, null, null, null,
                        null, null, null);

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                    do {

                        image = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex("photo"));

                    } while (c.moveToNext());

                }

                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0,
                        image.length);

                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Show Success",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }

}
```